# i try to delete a index from an array javascript, but its not working

Tags: javascript

here is my code

```
subjectData = [
     {name: 'a'},
     {name: 'b'},
     {name: 'c'},
]


eachStudent.subjectName= [
    'b', 'c'
]


this.eachStudent.subjectName.forEach((v) => {
  let index = this.subjectData.map((el) => el.name.toLowerCase()).indexOf(v.toLowerCase());
      if (index > -1) {
         this.subjectData.splice(index, 1)
      }
})
```

I want to remove indexs from subjectData which is exist in eachStudent.subjectName

and when i console  **el.name** and **v** I found that one el is similar but always return -1

Plz help

Comment: Can you please create a [mre], preferably using a code snippet

Comment: hi @NickParsons plz check now

Comment: Array.filter is the way to do this. But you are also modifying the very list you are iterating over, which is not recommended. Try to use the functional-style methods of Array for these types of problems and all of these issues usually go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's so much easier to do this with a one liner using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
subjectData = subjectData.filter((item => !subjectName.includes(item.name)));
```

Here's a working stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tly2yl